# Quasi-custom API Call Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

Basically I am trying to display data from WordPress site #1 on WordPress site #2, and to get around the issue of trying to connect to the database, I thought it might be smarter to make an API-like plugin to return the information.

My notion was to build a URL with a parameter which would be used to pull the information I need. Here's all I've got so far...

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_GET['post_id'] ) ) {

    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

    // use WordPress functionality to retrieve data with $post_id

    echo $stuff;

}
```

Let's say the location of this code is `/wp-content/plugins/custom-api.php`. I want to be able to visit, for example, the URL `/wp-content/plugins/custom-api.php?post_id=420` and have it spit back some information on the page (like post title, thumbnail, whatever).

The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to gain access to use the WordPress functions. I know normally with plugins you hook in a function, and then any WP functions you use will work.

Here, I'm not trying to hook in; I'm trying to hook out. If I use any WordPress native function, it's not recognized as existing. I'm kind of stumped at the moment. Any suggestions or links to resources I could mull over would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not need a plugin for this.  You can do it this way.

Say you are fetching data from WP1 to WP2 instances.

1. create a page in WP1.. say "Custom API" with url /custom-api/.
2. create a template in WP1 named "custom api" in WP1
3. assign page "Custom API" to template "custom api".

Since your template is a regular WordPress template you have access to all the WP functions.i.e. the ability to retrieve wordpress data.

1. in WP2, however you want to do it, make a web service call to
   /custom-api/ (the page you

create in step 1).

Comment: Very cool idea!!! You're a genius. All hail rxn. I'll be having a lot of fun with this...